# How do I redirect the output of a system() function to a variable?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
system("echo %username%");
```

I want to redirect its result to a variable, say `uname`.

How can I do it?

I am aware of the WinAPI but I want to do it this way.

Comment: You'll need a [`pipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: If what you need is the user name, consider using the OS native interfaces. `system` is not only not secure, but also _slow_ (a new process is spawned, etc). If you insist in recurring to another process, try using [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe). It's not possible to retrieve the output of a command invoked with `system`.

Comment: Alright, then for system("systeminfo"); where the output is large, how do I redirect it to a text file?

Comment: @blah: [popen](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25656c772226768b) for posix systems

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? The system command you are running is Windows-only, anyway.

Comment: My program is platform dependent.
More over, I want to redirect the output of systeminfo to a text file and I want this happen through c++ code.

Comment: @blah systeminfo to a text file... You can use `system("systeminfo >textfile");`

Comment: I did that. There's no other way right?

Comment: @blah There is, but you don't want to use it :)

Comment: Alright, so that system("systeminfo > textfile"); won't cause any problems right?

Comment: @blah: what do you mean by "problem"?

Comment: @blah: note that [`system("anything")`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) is a onee huge _Undefined Behaviour_

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Not undefined behavior, implementation defined.

Comment: @JamesKanze: So why at the end of page I posted there is written "If _command_ is not a _null pointer_, it causes _undefined behavior_."?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus The page is wrong.  (In addition, this sentence contradicts what the page says higher up, at least in part.  The behavior is well defined, up to the point you end up in the command interpreter.  At which point it becomes implementation defined.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick, ugly and dirty way is to redirect the output to a file and then read that file.

```
system("echo %username% > someFile.txt");
```

A more elaborated way is to use the `CreateProcess` API with the following command line: `cmd.exe /c echo %username%`

That API allows you to specify custom standard input and standard output. You can create a pipe for the standard output like this:

```
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
// 
if ( !CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) return -1;
```

And then use this pipe in the CreateProcess API. Something like this:

```
TCHAR szCmdline[]=TEXT("cmd.exe /c echo %username%");
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 
STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;

// Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 
// 
memset( &piProcInfo, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );

// Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
// This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
//
memset( &siStartInfo, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

// Create the child process. 
//    
bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL, 
      szCmdline,     // command line 
      NULL,          // process security attributes 
      NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
      TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
      0,             // creation flags 
      NULL,          // use parent's environment 
      NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
      &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
      &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
```

And then reads from the pipe with something like this:

```
DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

for (;;) 
{ 
      bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 
}
```

The process will be running asynchronously so you need to know when the process is terminated and do the proper cleanup. Therefore there is a bunch of details to learn here in order to make this work.

A complete example can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Since my program does lots of logging, I'd prefer the dirty way. Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing ugly and dirty in using `system` to output data to a file.  The available commands, and how the command string is interpreted, depends on the system you're running on, but if that isn't an issue for your application, then `system` is a perfectly good solution.

Comment: There is some exaggeration when I say ugly and dirty but the reason is that there is some limitations on this method since not everything can be nicely redirected by simply adding "> file.txt" at the end and it involves the creation of a file which also have some logistics problems: name the file, delete the file later, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to control the encoding of the file when doing things the "dirty" way? By default on Windows I get a Unicode text file. Is it possible to encode it differently?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is only to get the user name, have you considered `getenv`; `getenv( "username" )` will return it directly.

Otherwise, if you have more that you want to do, and want the results in a file...  The string you pass to `system` is passed to a command interpreter, so anything you could do in a command line in `cmd.exe` will work in `system`: file redirection, pipe to another process, etc.